# Is there a way to maintain session state with Watson speech recognition to avoid scrambled speaker identification?

Tags: ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I'm using Watson to perform speech to text including speaker identification (diarization). The quality is sometimes good and sometimes not, but there's one glaring flaw: I need to upload audio in chunks and Watson doesn't have any context across chunks, so the speaker identification is scrambled after the first chunk.

Suppose I record a conversation for an hour, but I want to upload in 5 minute chunks so I don't have to wait for the whole thing to end before I can start processing. What I'm finding is that in the first chunk, speakers A, B, C speak in that order and are identified as speakers 1, 2, and 3.

But then in the second chunk, it may be that the same people just happen to speak in the order C, A, B. Now **they** are identified as speakers 1, 2, and 3, and this is totally different from the first chunk and there's no way to assign them correctly.

So, is there a way to tell Watson that a series of audio chunks should maintain the same context or state, so this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the websockets API - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=node#recognize-audio-websockets - with `interimResults` set to `true`.

Comment: I am using web sockets, but I send off the audio in chunks, as indeed you have to, because the document states "You can pass a maximum of 100 MB ... of audio ... per recognition request", which, even at the fairly low resolution format that I'm using is less than an hour of audio, and I often need to transcribe 4 to 8 hour segments. My question is: how to maintain session state, especially speaker diarization, across those chunks.

Comment: Also, `interimResults` is about receiving the results as they are produced vs receiving the final results when complete. I don't think it has anything to do with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So are you finding that the speaker identification resets every 100MB ?

Comment: My chunks are generally smaller than that, but yes, each submission is treated independent of the previous one, causing the speaker identification to be scrambled form one to the next, making it impossible to carry speaker id across multiple submissions.

Comment: That is odd. Provided there isn't a large silence gap, they should be treated as a single audio track. Are you disconnecting the web-socket, and reconnecting for each chunk?

Comment: I am disconnecting, but I don't really have a choice about this. My application records a conversation that might go on for many hours, possibly a whole day. It might even happen in a place where the connection to the internet is off for a while in the middle. So I have a method for slicing the conversation into chunks of, say, 30 minutes and these get queued up for processing. If a chunk completes, it is removed from the queue and the results are added to another queue for processing. If the chunk fails, it remains in the queue for another attempt.

Comment: That attempt may need to happen after the user disconnects from the internet entirely, or shuts down for the day and goes home, or reboots, etc. so there's no way to keep the web socket open. So I need a way to open a **new** socket but pass some identifier to preserve the context/state of the running session.